# How to calculate using input from div input tags

Tags: javascript, html

I'm lost working on a computer science assignment and my teacher isn't available to help. I have a simple JS program that's supposed to subtract values from user input.

Here is my code:

```js
document.getElementById("calculateButton").addEventListener("click", calculate);

function calculate(){
        var exspendin = document.getElementById('exspendin');
        var avfundin = document.getElementById('avfundin');
        var total = 'exspendin' - 'avfundin';
        //var total = math.subtract('avfundin', 'exspendin')
        document.getElementById('calc');
        window.alert('total');
}
```

```html
<div><input type="text" id="avfundin" height="79" width="328" y="153.5" x="235.99999"  value="Input Available Funds"><div>
<div><input type="text" id="exspendin" height="79" width="328" y="292.5" x="235.99999" value="Input Expected Spending"><div>
<a id="calculateButton">Calculate</a>
```

**When I run, it prints `"total"` instead of the difference of the user input.**

How would I get it to do that?

Comment: Because you should `window.alert(total)` without `'`, but still, I never saw `x` and `y` in an input text

Comment: ```var total = 'exspendin' - 'avfundin'``` should be ```var total = +exspendin-  +avfundin```

Comment: If one of the answers on this page solved your problem please consider marking it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are some of the following problems:

**HTML**

- Using [`placeholder="Input Available Funds"`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_placeholder.asp) instead of `value="Input Available Funds"`

**Javascript**

1. using `window.alert`(**total**); instead of `window.alert`(**'total'**);
2. Using `document.getElementById('exspendin')`**.value** to get value instead of an `element`.
3. Using [`Number(exspendin)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) to convert from string to number.
4. Using `var total = Number(exspendin) - Number(avfundin);` instead of `var total = 'exspendin' - 'avfundin'`

```js
document.getElementById("calculateButton").addEventListener("click", calculate);

function calculate(){
    var exspendin = document.getElementById('exspendin').value;
    var avfundin = document.getElementById('avfundin').value;
    var total = Number(exspendin) - Number(avfundin);
    window.alert(total);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="avfundin" height="79" width="328" y="153.5" x="235.99999"  placeholder="Input Available Funds">
<div>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="exspendin" height="79" width="328" y="292.5" x="235.99999" placeholder='Input Expected Spending'>
<div>

<a id="calculateButton">Calculate</a>
```

---

> **placeholder:** Specifies a short hint (one word or a short phrase) that describes the expected value of the text field

Comment: @Avery Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help ^^!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
function calculate(){
    // you must get the value of the input element
    // trim() removes extra whitespace
    var exspendin = document.getElementById('exspendin').value.trim();
    var avfundin = document.getElementById('avfundin').value.trim();
    
    if(exspendin.length == 0 || avfundin.lenth == 0) {
        alert("Fields must not be empty");
        return;  // exit from the function so no more code gets executed
    }
    
    // convert string to integer
    exspendin = parseInt(exspendin);
    avfundin = parseInt(avfundin);
    
    // parseInt() returns NaN if the input could not be converted to integer
    // isNaN() checks if it's Not A Number
    if(isNaN(exspendin) || isNaN(avfundin)) {
        alert("Both fields must have an integer value");
        return;
    }
    
    // If the code got to here then both inputs are non empty integers
    var total = exspendin - avfundin;
    
    // write to div and alert
    document.getElementById('calc').innerHTML = "The total is: " + total;
    window.alert("The total is: " + total);
}
```

```html
<div><input type="text" id="avfundin" height="79" width="328" y="153.5" x="235.99999"  placeholder="Input Available Funds" value=""><div>
<div><input type="text" id="exspendin" height="79" width="328" y="292.5" x="235.99999" placeholder="Input Expected Spending" value=""><div>

<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate()" />

<div id="calc"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the value variable (to get the value of the numbers), and then use the Number function (to change the string to a number). Then just alert the subtracted pair.

```js
document.getElementById("calculateButton").addEventListener("click", calculate);

function calculate(){
        var exspendin = Number(document.getElementById('exspendin').value); //get the number value of the first input
        var avfundin = Number(document.getElementById('avfundin').value); //get the number value of the second input
        var total = exspendin - avfundin; //subtract the two
        window.alert(total); //alert the total
}
```

```html
<div><input type="text" id="avfundin" height="79" width="328" y="153.5" x="235.99999"  aria-label="Input Available Funds"><div>
<div><input type="text" id="exspendin" height="79" width="328" y="292.5" x="235.99999" aria-label="Input Expected Spending"><div>
<a id="calculateButton">Calculate</a>
```